# Silverlight Screen Blurred after Flip animation

Tags: silverlight, animation, screen-resolution

I have created a flip animation to go from a list of items to an edit dialogue. For example, the user sees a list of items, double-clicks on an item to edit it and the screen flips to display the edit dialogue with the details.

I have the actual animation working except that items on the screen are slightly blurred. When I flip back to the list that is also blurred.

Can anyone suggest the reason for this. I have shown below how I have achieved the flip.

```
             <ContentControl x:Name="EditPtrMainContent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="FlipToEditStart">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="90" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentProjection" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="FlipToEditEnd">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="270" To="360" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentProjection" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY"/>
                    </Storyboard>

                    <Storyboard x:Name="FlipToListStart">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="-90" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentProjection" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="FlipToListEnd">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="-270" To="-360" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentProjection" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ContentControl.Resources>

                <ContentControl.Projection>
                    <PlaneProjection x:Name="ContentProjection"/>
                </ContentControl.Projection>

            </ContentControl>
```

And in the code-behind (essentially an MVVM app but I am happy with animation control being in the view as it is visual)

```
        public EditPtrView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
        FlipToEditStart.Completed += OnFlipToEditStartCompleted;
        FlipToListStart.Completed += OnFlipToListStartCompleted;
    }

    void OnFlipToListStartCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditPtrMainContent.Content = new EditPtrView();
        FlipToListEnd.Begin();
    }

    void OnFlipToEditStartCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditPtrMainContent.Content = new NamedTransferView();
        FlipToEditEnd.Begin();
    }

    void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // register for MVVM Light messages
        AppMessages.SetFocusMessage.Register(this, OnSetFocus);
        AppMessages.CloseScreenMessage.Register(this, OnCloseScreen);

        AppMessages.ViewLoadedMessage.Send(ViewTypes.BookingsListView);
    }

    void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AppMessages.SetFocusMessage.Unregister(this, OnSetFocus);
        AppMessages.CloseScreenMessage.Unregister(this, OnCloseScreen);
    }

    #region MVVM Light Message Delegates

    private void OnCloseScreen(string screenName)
    {
        switch (screenName)
        {
            case "PtrEdit":
                FlipToListStart.Begin();
                break;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void TransfersDataGridDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowEditScreen();
    }

    private void EditPtrButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowEditScreen();
    }

    private void ShowEditScreen()
    {
        FlipToEditStart.Begin();
    }
```

As you can see I start the first half of the animation on double-click (or button click) and animate to 90 degrees. Then when this animation completes I change the content of the ContentControl to the new screen and start the second animation to go from 270 to 360 degrees. With an MVVM Light Messenger call from the edit screen I do a reverse animation to go back to the list. All of this works OK but, as I said, the screens go slightly blurred. I am not imagining it because the edit screen is a View/ViewModel that is also used elsewhere and so it is easy to compare.
Is there something that needs to be done at the end of the animation to redraw the screen correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following event handlers. -360 or 360 degree rotation causes the problem and must be replaced by 0 after the animation.

```
FlipToEditEnd.Completed += (a, b) => { ContentProjection.RotationY = 0.0; };
FlipToListEnd.Completed += (a, b) => { ContentProjection.RotationY = 0.0; };
```